# Is it possible to send a private message to a fan of my page as the page itself?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-messenger

I want to know if I can send a private message to a fan of my page as the sender is the page itself which is created by me so that the fan can not identify me?

Answer (score 1):

As of now you can not initiate a conversation with a fan. If the person starts the conversation, yes, you can. But you can't send the first message.

What you can do is create a post (on your page) for that person asking him/her to contact you and tag the person.

Answer (score -2):

Facebook has recently changed this process and you can now send messages as a page admin.

Comment: Can you expand on this at all? A blog post? Help page?